# connecting sybase by using DSN + SQLAnywhere

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere, dsn

I am connecting sybase by using DSN + SQLAnywhere.. But not able to find the driver. Please suggest me suitable Driver.
Program:

Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver");
Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:SQLAnywhere:MYDB");

error
Unable to get a connection from Sybase database No suitable driver found for jdbc:SQLAnywhere:SHRDB java.sql.SQLException:No suitable driver found for jdbc:SQLAnywhere:MYDB

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the sajdbc4.jar, try this:

```
try {
   Class.forName("sybase.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver");
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlanywhere:dsn=*;uid=*;pwd=*");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

for older versions (SQLAnywhere 11) this driver should work: "sybase.jdbc.sqlanywhere.IDriver"